# Using tight_layout() in python creates unnecessary whitespace

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using tight_layout() to fit a plot since the x-label was cut off, however as can be seen in the plot I get an unnecessary amount of whitespace both to the left and below the figure. How can I minimize the amount of whitespace around the figure but still keep all the text visible? I tried using

```
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
```

but this only cuts the whitespace on the top and to the right of the image.

Time series plot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually set the amount of whitespace on your plot by using the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#plot your actual data here

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.07, right=0.8, top=0.9, bottom=0.2)
#change the values above so that your figure and axes labels are all visible

plt.show()
```

By changing the values inside `subplots_adjust` you can set the right layout for your plot.

Comment: I find it odd that this process can not be automated, say together with the tight_layout() function. This, however, solves the issue when few plots has to be generated and can be manually adjusted by hand. Note: should be plt.subplots_... instead of just subplots_...

Comment: Yes you are right, I have edited my answer. I'm not aware of any way to do this automatically, or why matplotlib itself doesn't have some sort of auto scaling to keep all labels on the figure.